# powershell -and operator with Test-Path syntax error

Tags: powershell, syntax-error, operators

In the code below I can use the -and operator to make a compound if statement, but when using Test-Path with -and there is a syntax error.

What is the proper way to use -and with a command like Test-Path?

```
$a = 1
$b = 1
$c = 1
if ($a -eq $b -and $a -eq $c ) {
    write-host "Variables are equal."
}
$path1 = "C:\Windows"
$path2 = "C:\Users"
if (Test-Path $path1 -and Test-Path $path2) {
    write-host "paths exist."
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put brackets around your usages of Test-Path then it works, i.e.

```
$path1 = "C:\Windows"
$path2 = "C:\Users"
if ((Test-Path $path1) -and (Test-Path $path2)) {
    write-host "paths exist."
}
```

Comment: Is it a regional thing to call parenthesis brackets?

Comment: @AustinFrench more a case of having to type 9 chars instead of 11 ;) Although it would be better again to call them braces; only 6 chars.

Comment: @AustinFrench: Yes: Commonwealth countries (the UK and former colonies) use the term "brackets" for `(` and `)`, whereas US English refers to these characters as "parentheses" (singular: "parenthesis").

Answer (score 2):

[DeanOC's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44058190/45375) provides an effective solution.

As for ***why* the parentheses (brackets) are needed**:

PowerShell has ***two* fundamental parsing modes**:

- ***argument* mode**, which works like traditional *shells*
- ***expression* mode**, which works like traditional *programming languages*.

Running [`Get-help about_Parsing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing) provides an introduction to these modes.

- `Test-Path $path1` and `Test-Path $path2` *in isolation* are parsed in *argument* mode.
- Operator `-and` can only be used in *expression* mode.
- In order to use the output of the argument-mode `Test-Path` commands in expression mode, they must be enclosed in `(...)`:

  - Use of **`(...)` forces a new parsing context**, and
  - **the *1st* token of a given parsing context determines whether it is parsed in argument or expression mode.**

---

Another thing to consider is **PowerShell's pervasive support for *collections***, which often allows you to operate at a **higher level of abstraction**:

```powershell
$paths = "C:\Windows", "C:\Users" # define *array* of input paths
if ((Test-Path $paths) -notcontains $False) { # See if ALL paths exist.
  "ALL paths exist."
}
```

- `Test-Path` accepts an *array* of paths to test, and outputs a corresponding *array* of Booleans indicating the respective existence.
- Operator `-notcontains` tests non-membership in the LHS array; in other words: if *no* Boolean returned by `Test-Path` is `$False`, the implication is that *all* input paths exist.
- Note that `Write-Host` was deliberately omitted, because in order **to send something to PowerShell's *success stream* (the analog to *stdout* in traditional shells), you don't need an explicit output command at all**, and, conversely, `Write-Host` actually *bypasses* the success stream - see [this blog post](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/).